# iphone application client - server user authentication practices

Tags: php, iphone

I am going to create a iPhone application that will be having the user login (username/pass) mechanism. on the server side i am using PHP.

i want to know the best practices for this kind of client/server authentication and session management.

looking for replies. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a token given by the server once it receives the correct userName and passord so every call to the web service by the device is "authenticated" with the received token.

1. so you send user name and password to the server from device
2. server gives back a token to the device
3. the device makes every request with the token, ie: URL/webSErvice/token

Answer (score 0):

the easy way to do is to passed the plained Username & encoded Password

and use the json payload , and php is easy to proceed json :

the data format may like this:

```
{
   "action" : "login",
   "data" :{
        "usr" : "somebody",
        "pwd" : "1f3870be274f6c49b3e31a0c6728957f"
    }
}
```

usually  the password hashed to a MD5 code

then server will return the result of auth

```
{
    "success" : "true",
    "data" :{
        //some data
    }
}
```

of course,  use the **HTTPS** connection is more safer